# MSVS 2010 Team explorer vs TFS 2012 Beta

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, beta

After installing TFS 2012 Express Beta x32 problems connecting old remote TFS 2010 server.

When I try to open Source Control for old TFS 2010 server - recieve error:

Team Foundation Error
Method not Found: 'Boolean
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.OwnerNameMatches(System.String)'.

Is it possible to fix this problem. Can't access code files. Team system works ok. Documents are available also.

Comment: I don't understand, is this VS11 -> TFS2010 or VS2010 -> TFS11 Express? Your tags say this is all 2010 -> 2010.

Comment: I use VS2010 + remote TFS 2010. After installing TFS2012Express got error "OwnerNameMatches" and i dont know what to do with that except clean reinstall of win7!

Comment: Where have you seen something named "TFS2012"?

Comment: I do also get this error. But i did not find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear on exactly what you did and where you did it? For starters, there's no such thing as TFS 2012, but I'm assuming you're talking about the TFS 11 beta.

Did you install TFS11 Express Beta on the same machine where you run Visual Studio 2010? Or did you install the TFS11 *Team Client* on your Visual Studio 2010 system? Did you also install Visual Studio 11 on that same machine? Are you now getting this error in VS2010?

Without knowing more about your setup, my guess is that you installed a new version of the TFS client tools and now your VS2010 is getting mismatched versions of the assemblies. (In particular, the method it's complaining about does not exist in the 2010 version of the client; I assume its new in v11.)

I had similar problems, though not TFS related, when installing VS11 side-by-side with VS2010; the ultimate fix was to uninstall VS2010 completely, then reinstall and re-service-pack VS2010. I'd also suggest not installing VS11 or TFS11 on a production machine until it's out of beta, unless you're willing to deal with this exact type of problem. (It's called *beta* for a reason...)

Comment: I don't quite remember the right order, but you're correct. As far as i remember, i've installed tfs12 beta "over" VS2010 without sp1.
Without right solution i've reinstalled os completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try the KB2662296 hotfix:

[Microsoft Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)